# Keras Tensorflow: Why this error on using Tensor Dataset returned by tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset() in call to model.fit?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have training data and validation data in two csv files, each containing a target column. I am trying to load these using a Data API Dataset, and feed to the model.fit() method. I am using Keras 2.8.0

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import metrics

print(tf.__version__)

TRAINING_DATA_DATASET = 'train_data_Dataset1.csv'   
VALIDATION_DATA_DATASET =  'validation_data_Dataset1.csv'


train_data_set=tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
       file_pattern = TRAINING_DATA_DATASET,
       batch_size=1024, 
       label_name='target',
       ignore_errors=True)

validation_data_set=tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
       file_pattern = VALIDATION_DATA_DATASET,
       batch_size=1024, 
       label_name='target',
       ignore_errors=True)

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop",
              loss="binary_crossentropy",
              metrics=[metrics.BinaryAccuracy(threshold = 0.5)])


model.fit(
       train_data_set,
       steps_per_epoch=TRAIN_DATA_SIZE // 1024,
       epochs= 3 ,
       validation_data=validation_data_set,
       validation_steps=VALIDATION_DATA_SIZE // BATCH_SIZE,
       verbose = 1)
```

On the call to mode.fit(), the following error is returned:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Layers in a Sequential model should only have a single input tensor. 

Received: inputs=OrderedDict([('NumberOfPeriods', <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(1024,) dtype=float32>), 
    ('P_2:average', <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(1024,) dtype=float32>), 
    ('P_2:average outlier1', <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(1024,) dtype=int32>), 
    ('P_2:average outlier2', <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:3' shape=(1024,) dtype=int32>), 
    ('P_2:average outlier3', <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:4' shape=(1024,) dtype=int32>), 
    ('P_2:stddev', <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:5' shape=(1024,) dtype=float32>)]).
Consider rewriting this model with the Functional API.
```

Whilst it says WARNING, the entire call to model.fit() failed. Clearly the input it not the correct shape, but I thought since Keras v2, it was possible to pass Datasets directly to model.fit().    What must be done to the dataset before being passed to model.fit (and later model.predict)?    I have not yet tried rewriting to use the Functional API instead, as I cant see how that would change the input shape. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i don't know the reason behind this but i found a way to get it to fit in the model.The reason behind is that data type is in order dict form and you need to convert it tf tensors data type.

[Coding sample i used to convert ordered dict to tensor form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxYHd.png)

In the above picture, i used tf.stack statement to convert tf ordered dict to tf tensor datatype and then fit it to the model and it worked!.Well i applied it on titanic dataset but you can apply it on your dataset.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).